# Refused to connect to 'https://rpc-mainnet.matic.network/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, rpc, mern

After deploying my MERN app to heroku, I get this error on the browser console. Even though I specified the correct CSP directives. This is the meta tag it renders on the browser

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://rpc-mainnet.matic.network/; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; ">
```

What am I doing wrong?